# Python concatanate files

Tags: python, file, text

file 1.csv:

```
traider1,domain.net,tomb,Raider1
traider,domain.net,tomb,Raider
```

file 2.txt:

```
TECH-1377
TECH-1366
```

How to combine these 2 files into 3rd ?

so i can get 3.csv:

```
traider1,domain.net,tomb,Raider1,TECH-1377
traider,domain.net,tomb,Raider,TECH-1366
```

i tried :

```
import fileinput

files= ['1.csv','2.txt']

allfiles = fileinput.input(files)

for line in allfiles: # this will iterate over lines in all the files
    print(line)
```

and got

```
traider1,domain.net,tomb,Raider1

traider,domain.net,tomb,Raider

TECH-1377

TECH-1366
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
with open('file 1.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()              #Read file1

with open('file 2.csv', 'r') as f2:
    data2 = f2.readlines()            #Read file2

with open('file 2.csv', 'w') as f3:
    writer = csv.writer(f3, delimiter=',')
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        val = "{0},{1}".format(line.strip(), data2[i].strip())
        writer.writerow(val.split(","))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but doesn't work: `writer.writerow(line.extend(data2[i]))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'`

Comment: Updated snippet. Can you try now